# Mapping to the custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So far I have my routes like this: ( **out of learning purposes I am curious to get it working with nested resources technique**, but if you think this will get too complicated please feel free to suggest any other way of routing technique too)

```
  resources :management, only: [:show] do
    resources :report, only: [:show], controller: 'report' do
      member do
         # hmm what to write in here?!
      end
    end
  end
```

my GOAL is to have a URL like this:

```
/managment/SOME_ID_WE_PASS_/report
/managment/1/report
```

But still can't figure out how exactly to write that route? Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need nested resources.

```
resources :crowd_management, only: [:show] do
  get :exec_report, on: :member
end
```

That will produce:

`/crowd_management/:id` mapped to `CrowdManagementController#show`
`/crowd_management/:id/exec_report` mapped to `CrowdManagementController#exec_report`

The helper methods will be:

```
crowd_management_path
exec_report_crowd_management_path
```

You can run `rake routes` for a detailed list of all your routes.

Comment: is this way of nesting, the ones you have and the even the second non-working one that I had, are these really meant for stuff that have a has_many, belongs_to relation? like Article and Comments... Because in my case the nature of "manager" and "report" is not really like that at all . So still would be viable to do it with nested? or my own one liner route was good too? –

Comment: I think there are two different things here. There is resource routing, as in my answer. You can pass additional routes to a block under "resources" but this isn't really nesting. Then there is nested resource routing, as in your example, when there is a "resources" inside of another "resources" and yes this is usually for "has_many" relationships.

Comment: If you're saying that "manager" and "report" aren't associated with each other, then why do you want a path like "/crowd_management/:id/exec_report"? That kind of path would suggest that they are associated.